# .htaccess RewriteRule with two different conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two different URLs:

1.: `mysite.com/file.php`

2.: `mysite.com/**articles**.php?article=**something**`

I would like to rewrite `mysite.com/file.php` to `mysite.com/file`.

AND

I would like to rewrite `mysite.com/**articles**.php?article=something` to `mysite.com/**news**/**something**`

I tried this but it's not working.

It rewrite `mysite.com/file.php` to `mysite.com/file`, but does not rewrite `mysite.com/**articles**.php?article=**something**` to `mysite.com/**news**/**something**`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?\ ]+)\.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !exception.php 
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)(/*)$ /articles.php?article=$1 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

(There is one exception in the code: `exception.php` which I don't want to rewrite.)

Can you please correct my code? I've been working on this for 4 days, I've read everything, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```bash
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect for file.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?exception\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(file)\.php/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite for php files.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]

##external + internal rewrite rules for articile.php here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/articles\.php\?article=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ articles.php?article=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, it is nearly working, but now, when I write mysite.com/anyfile.php, it does not rewrite to mysite.com/anyfile, it only rewrite when I write file.php. I want to do the opposite :)

Comment: @PéterGergő, could you please try changing line `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(file)\.php/?\s [NC]` **to** `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php/?\s [NC]` once on my rules and then try once.

Comment: Thanks, that's good, but how do I add the exception.php file as an exception? Simply `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !exception.php` right after RewriteEngine ON?

Comment: @PéterGergő, kindly check my edited rules. Kindly do let me know how this goes.

Comment: Can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74325127/htaccess-rewriterule-causes-404-error-why