# Htaccess RewriteRule causes 404 error. Why?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

This is my code, it works almost perfectly, but if I write `mysite.com/news/` instead of `mysie.com/news`, it gives me 404 error. What is the problem?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/category\.php\?catid=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/categories/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/new\.php\?title=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(exception\.php|admin) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^news/categories/([^/]*)$ category.php?catid=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ new.php?title=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please try changing rule `RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ new.php?title=$1 [NC,QSA,L]` **to** `RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/?$ new.php?title=$1 [NC,QSA,L]` once and see what happens?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, because it do nothing, the operation is the same with both codes. Perhaps an even better solution would be if there is a / at the end, but there is nothing after the slash, so rewrite it and not have the slash. In all cases, not only in the news/. Can this be solved? Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13

Is it a good solution, if I add this code right after `RewriteEngine On`?

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Am I doing something wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailing slashes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```